# Searching list using react-virtualized-select is laggy

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a large list (~10,000 items) that I am using react-virtualized-select to render in a searchable dropdown. The items are searched as a user types (default react-virtualized-select behavour).

react-virtualized-select is recommended here: [Big list performance with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033442/big-list-performance-with-react)

Although react-virtualized-select is designed specifically for this purpose I am still finding the performance slugglish. Am I missing something I can do to optimise performance? (Asides from reducing the items in the list).

Looking at the Chrome performance tools it seems like stripDiacrtics(?) and the actual filtering (filterOptions) are taking the bulk of the time, as would be expected with such a big list.

[image]

```
<VirtualizedSelect
  key={records.GUID}
  labelKey='currentScientificName'
  options={records}
  matchProp='label' // react-select v1 prop - Don't think this is used by VirtualizedSelect
  matchPos='start' // react-select v1 prop - Don't think this is used by  VirtualizedSelect
/>
```

Example:
https://afisher88.github.io/virtualized-select-test/