# Rendering large amount of items prevents other functions to work before render completes

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to find out how to prevent rendering a large amount of data freezing other functionalities in a React component.

In the code, I have a button called Render, which renders 30000 items and another button, Reset, that removes them.

Once I click Render, I am unable to click the other button, Reset because the component is busy rendering 30000 items for the time being.

I want to be able to click Reset button while the component is trying to render the items. Please help me with ways to resolve this issue.

```
const ItemsComponent = () => {
  const [displayItems, setDisplayItems] = useState(false);

  const items = Array.from(Array(30000)).map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={index}>
        Item {index + 1}
      </li>
    )
  });

  const renderItems = () => { setDisplayItems(true) }
  const resetItems = () => { setDisplayItems(false) }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={renderItems}>Render</button>
      <button onClick={resetItems}>Reset</button>
      <ul>
        { displayItems ? items : null }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big list performance with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033442/big-list-performance-with-react)

Comment: No, my question is about unblocking buttons or other components while a large list is being rendered.

Comment: Instead of rendering all the 30,000 items at a time why don't you try using lazy loading which increases the performance to great extent and it will neither block your buttons.