# How to deal with display errors when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a web application showing all manageable shops by the current user logging in. There is an array on the client side continuing receiving shops from a database.

In react's point of view, the shops in the render looks like bellow,

```
//display all shops
...
let shops=appState.shops;
...
for (let i = 0; i < shops.length; i += 2) {
...
    //e1 and e2 are 2 shop information display areas aligned in a row
    shopViews.push(<div key= {`shopView${i}`} style = {{width: '100%'}}>{e1}{e2}</div>);
...
}
return (<{ShopViews}>);
```

When scrolling the viewing area, the application detects whether the user reaches the application bottom.

```
handleScroll=(event)=>{
    //show waiting circle when the user reaches the page bottom. 
    //this indicates that the user should wait until the new fetch finishes.
};
```

But, when I scroll up--with displayed shops already fetched in--I found that display errors like bellow commonly happen.

[image]

The normal display is

[image]

Any ideas to resolve this display issue? Anything is welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033442/big-list-performance-with-react

Comment: maybe this would help: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window

Answer (score 0):

The wrong display is caused by the combination of rendering and at-the-same-time scrolling. So, I change the control flow to only render when scrolling to the very bottom of the current page.