# JavaScript / React - Async array map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using **React Native**. I want to create a **very** long list.
Each element in the **List** component is a **ListItem** component.
My problem is that the component is loading **too much time**. The List is created with **Array.map()**.
Please have a look at the code.

My question is whether it is somehow possible to create **async map()** so elements in the list will load one by one and the component won't wait that much?

Tried something like [this](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await-array-map/) but nothing works for me. Can someone help please?

```
class List extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // very big array
        var list = [...Array(5000).keys()];
        return (
            <Content>
                {
                    list.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <ListItem text={item} key={index}/>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </Content>
        );
    }
}

class ListItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Button>
                <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
            </Button>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `so elements in the list will load one by one and the component won't wait that much` if the component "doesn't wait", how would the 5000 list items get rendered?

Comment: @JaromandaX this is exactly what I am trying to achive... :)

Comment: You can use lazy load in which load say 10 items first and then when user scrolls down load extra 10 items. while loading next 10 items just append it to existing list.

Comment: @AnilKumar this is not a desired behavior. They should load one-by-one until the end immediately. I just don't want to make the component waiting...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033442/big-list-performance-with-react

Comment: @Vandesh this is a little different problem

Answer (score 0):

The async map code you linked to works, it just doesn't do what you want it to. The time it takes to render 5000 components from your array still takes a long time, async will just allow you to asynchronously do stuff on its completion.

From a UX perspective, you almost never need to render that many elements. Instead, you should load the data in as you need it (user scrolls down to a certain point).

**Option 1**

So the data flow logic would look something like:

1. Load first 100 entries to display.
2. User needs more entries
   (scrolls down the list further) so you make a request
3. Load the
   next 100 entries to display.

This is a common pattern if you are using an API to interface with your data.

**Option 2**

If you have the array in memory, you could try dividing the array into smaller chunks with Array.slice() and rendering each of those asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Using async wont fix the issue. The size of array is big and mapping means running a for loop so for loop for let's say 5000 items will take time.

> Restrict the size of array or increment them in bundles of 100 as you
>   go.